# finding PMF of a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$ be a random variable such that $\forall k\in\mathbb{N} \;P(X>k+1) = \frac12P(X>k)$. Find the probability mass function of $X$.

What I've been able to do until now :

$$P(X>k+1) = \frac12P(X>k)$$
$$P(X>k+1) = \frac12P((X=k+1)\cup(X>k+1))$$
$$\frac12P(X>k+1) = \frac12P(X=k+1)$$
$$P(X>k+1) = P(X=k+1)$$

this equality is true $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$ so it is also true for $k = 0$

$$P(X>1) =P(X=1) $$
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} P(X=k) = P(X=1) $$

I assume that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X=k) = 1 \implies \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} P(X=k) = 1 -  P(X=1) $ then $P(X=1) =\frac12$. I am not sure if I'm doing it right until now and I'm also stuck so please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $P(X>k) = 2^{1-k}P(X>1)$ for $k>0$ by induction. Then as $P(X>1)={1\over 2}$ as $1=P(X>0)=2P(X>1)$ we see that for $k=1$ we have $P(X=1)=1-P(X>1)={1\over 2}$ and similarly

> $$P(X=k) = P(X>k-1)-P(X>k)=(2^{2-k}-2^{1-k})P(X>1)=2^{-k}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $0\in\mathbb N$ here.

Your method works but there is a shorter route:  $$P(X>1)=\frac12P(X>0)=\frac12.1=\frac12$$
and consequently:$$P(X=1)=1-P(X>1)=1-\frac12=\frac12$$

By induction it can be shown for $k=1,2,\dots$ that: $$P(X>k)=2^{-k}$$ and consequently: $$P(X=k+1)=P(X>k)-P(X>k+1)=2^{-k}-2^{-k-1}=2^{-k-1}$$

For $k=1,2,\dots$ it is proved is now that: $$P(X=k)=2^{-k}$$